# K6 dial tcp 127.0.0.1:44353: connect: connection refused

Tags: .net, k6

I'm trying to set up a workflow on github adding my tests but also performance tests. I give it the url I use on postman but it doesn't seem to work on github. I might miss something obbvious here any response would be greatly appreciated.

This is the error

```
time="2023-01-15T23:19:44Z" level=warning msg="Request Failed" error="Get \"https://localhost:44353/Test\": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:6000: connect: connection refused"
```

This is what the test looks like

```
import http from 'k6/http';
import {sleep, check} from 'k6';

export const options = {
    stages: [
        { duration: '30s', target: 150 },
        { duration: '1s', target: 150 },
        { duration: '30s', target: 150 },
    ],
    thresholds: {
        http_req_duration: ['p(99)<200'],
        http_req_failed: ['rate<0.01'],
    },
    
};

const base_url = 'https://localhost:44353'
export default () => {
    const responses = http.batch([
        ['GET', `${base_url}/Test`]
    ])
    check(responses[0], {
        'status is' : res => res.status === 200
    })
    sleep(1);
}
```

This is what it looks like in the dotnet.yml file. I'm using .net 5 might that matter

```
- name: Peformance Load test
      uses: grafana/k6-action@v0.2.0
      with:
        filename: orenji-backend.Tests/PerformanceTests/LoadTest.js
```

Comment: `localhost` is always your local machine/host/vm/pod. I doubt that your test and your server are running on the host (and they really shouldn't be!). Use an IP address that is actually reachable from GitHub's action runner.